# Density plot on Iris dataset with R

Tags: r, density-plot

I want to plot a density plot of my dataset. This is my code:

```
    data <- iris
    plot(density(data$Sepal.Length), 
    main="Density Plot", ylab="Frequency",
    sub=paste("Skewness:", round(e1071::skewness(data$Sepal.Length), 2)))
```

My goal is to set up a plot function to select only `virginica` data. Is it possible?

Comment: Subset before plotting: `data <- iris[ iris$Species == "virginica", ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can be
data <- iris

```
data <- data %>% filter(data$Species == "virginica")
plot(density(data$Sepal.Length), 
     main="Density Plot", ylab="Frequency",
     sub=paste("Skewness:", round(e1071::skewness(data$Sepal.Length), 2)))
```